# Adler-32 in Multilevel Security Environment Safe Practices

Tags: security, hash, adler32

I'm implementing a multilevel security environment on several several web servers running Debian. I've done quite a bit of reading on fast hash checking algorithms to compliment the other security components.

It seems Adler-32 is quite fast and compact (which I'm quite fond of), although I understand it can be 'easily' forged. This aspect of it makes me a bit nervous, so is there some way to safeguard against it being forged somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  CRCs can also be easily forged.  If you are worried about forging (and make sure that you understand *why* you are worried about forging), then you need to use a cryptographically secure hash.  E.g. [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

Answer (score 0):

No.  You cannot condition Adler-32 to be secure, for a simple reason which will affect even a perfect non-reversible hash function you might hope to find.

No 32-bit checksum or digest can be meaningfully resistant to attack because there are only four billion possible outcomes in a modified message.  This means that to brute-force a collision takes a comparatively trivial amount of time.

To put this in real-world terms, hashcash is giving me an estimate of 874 seconds to brute-force 32 bits of of a SHA1 digest.  Any checksum which you choose for speed is going to get proportionally easier.

That's even before you start to consider potential weaknesses in the algorithm which might yield a more efficient approach than brute force, and the use of GPU computing to accelerate the attack.